# download codebox spoiler from forum

Tags: download, forum

is there a possability to save forum codeboxes ( / spoilers ) to a file?
Normally there are only "show spolier" buttons, but what if you would want to save the complete webpage with hundreds of codeboxes (or just from a thread)?
If you save the complete webpage in firefox, codeboxes are not saved, nor showable afterwards.
I could not find anything considering this topic online and hope somebody can help me, as I do not know if this would even be possible in any way.

Comment: this is  a broad question

Comment: I want to archive Sony-Ericsson patches all at once from this forum site: 
http://supertrubka.org/newbb_plus/viewtopic.php?topic_id=4357